# SQL Server - What ports to open on firewall to get access

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [port number of SQL Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/54505/port-number-of-sql-server)

SQL Server - What ports to open on firewall to get access

Answer (score 1):

It depends. What port is SQL Server bound to? In most cases it's going to be port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

TCP 1433 should be enough if you use default server instance only.

If there're several instances, you need TCP ports for them as well (port number is configured for each instance).

For SQL Browser service you need to open UDP 1434. Otherwise, you want be able to see the server in some GUI dialogs (though could type the server name manually) and to connect to the instances by their names (though could connect by directly speciying the port).

Answer (score 0):

1433 and 1434 are correct for base access. However, if you are using MSDTC then you have a new new can of worms that you need to address. There is a Microsoft KB article on implementing port restrictions for RPC that you will need to follow to restrict the ports that your SQL Server clients will use when communicating with your SQL Server for a transaction that requires MSDTC.

The article is: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

> This article describes the TCP/IP port numbers that Microsoft SQL Server requires to communicate over a firewall. The default SQL Server port is 1433, and client ports are assigned a random value between 1024 and 5000.

[...]

> SQL Server is a Winsock application that communicates over TCP/IP by using the sockets network library. SQL Server listens for incoming connections on a particular port. The default port for SQL Server is 1433. The port doesn't need to be 1433, but 1433 is the official Internet Assigned Number Authority (IANA) socket number for SQL Server.

Note that more recent versions of SQL server will use dynamic port allocations for named instances by default which you might want to change:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938/en-us