# SQL Server - What ports to open on firewall to get access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [port number of SQL Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/54505/port-number-of-sql-server)

In SQL Server - What ports need to be opened on the firewall to get access

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault. Is this default or named instance?

Answer (score 2):

By default, MS SQL Server doesn't have the TCP/IP protocol enabled.
You have to open Sql Server Configuration Manager, enable the TCP/IP protocol, customize port if needed (default is 1433), and restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify much information, I'll go with the half-a-second Google route:

http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=sql+server+ports

Leads to:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify tcp/ip port 1433

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

By default, TCP port 1433 is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default the SQL server instances run on port number 1433. But I think it can be configured to run on other ports too.

You can find on which port your sql instance is running by following this -

Using the GUI: In SQL Server 2005, you can use the SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Look under SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration and look at the TCP port for the TCP/IP protocol.