# changing the default port of Mcrosoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vps, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [port number of SQL Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/54505/port-number-of-sql-server)

Can any one guide me on How can I change the default port of Microsoft SQL Server in my Windows VPS?

I am using Windows 2008 as my operating System and Microsoft SQL 2008 in my VPS

please help me asap.

Comment: Before asking a question like this be sure to search the internet and ServerFault.  This is a common question and is well documented throughout the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change alternative port for MSSQL remote access, please perform following steps :

Go to Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Under SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS -> TCP/IP -> under protocol tab Enable it.
-> Under IP Address Tab give Port Number in front of TCP Port field.

Click on Apply & OK.

Restart SQL Services.

Now you can login to your SQL Server using your given port.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you open Sql Server Confirguration Manager on the VPS (Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server XXXX -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager).

Expand Native Configuration and select Client Protocols and then right click on TCP/IP on the right hand side.

Change the value in default port to whatever value you want it to be instead, apply and restart your SQL server.